# iPhone - Auto retrieve missing files in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, file, import

When changing the file and folder structure into the finder, is there a way to let XCode find the missing files in the project folder instead of having to import again the whole thing and reorganize the project structure after the import process ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - select a number of files all in the same directory.  Now pull up the right sidebar, and in the "Identity and Type" section, under the "Location" dropdown, there's a small grey box.

Click on that box and you'll be prompted either to provide a location for the file, or if you have selected multiple files you'll be prompted to choose a directory where all of the files can be found.

Comment: Helmstetter Geln : Thank you, that works, but one must not ask to much to this function :-)

Comment: Just to clarify further based on the current Xcode 4 interface: 1) select the file or files in the left hand Project Navigator (the folder icon); 2. In the right sidebar click on "File Inspector" which is the leftmost icon resembling a page; 3. In the "Identity and Type" section, there is a grey box labeled "Location". Click on the small icon to the lower left that resembles a file browser - this will come up with a file browser to locate the file. Voila, you are done.

Comment: Can someone screenshot this "right sidebar...leftmost icon resembling a page"...I seriously cannot find it.